# Build failed while creating signed apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

im trying to build this project in signed mode(i.e playstore Google) , so that other of my friends from the school hostel could download and test, i have tried many documentations, but i doesnt work pls help me, this is the gradle(build.gradle)

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
    }

    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
     if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the       local.properties file.")
}

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
   if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   android {
         compileSdkVersion 29
   }

 

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.thealphamerc.flutter_twitter_clone_dev"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

       signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

     

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   And here is the error in terminal

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    Where:
    Build file 'C:\Users\MTGSTCKN\Documents\flutter_twitter_clone\android\app\build.gradle' line: 39

    What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

    Could not find method lintOptions() for arguments [build_8bee7k9ov9n3733ekoixc4hsh$_run_closure3@7fad45fd] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

    Try:
```

Try: n
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

```
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done 60.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you generate your keystore file?

Answer (score 0):

Your build.gradle should look like this on release

Check documentation: [Official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties") // change to your keystore file name
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.thealphamerc.flutter_twitter_clone_dev" 
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger() 
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: thank you guys, the problem is now solved